# Including graphics that were converted in a separate build directory

Tags: graphics, pdftex, epstopdf

I'm using [BasicTeX 2019](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) which includes pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019).

I've installed the `repstopdf` tool and added this near the top of my document:

```latex
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=build/}
```

Then I include an EPS file like so:

```latex
\epsfig{file=stride1.eps}
% or \includegraphics{stride1}
```

This correct creates a converted file called `build/stride1-eps-converted-to.pdf` which contains the expected content.

But in the produced document, it's blank where the figure should go. What is missing?

---

If I *don't* include the `\usepackage{epstopdf}` it does work, but the converted files are placed in the top level directory, which is undesirable.

I also tried setting `\graphicspath` to the same build directory but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what seems to have worked:

1. I switched from `epsfig` to `graphicx` (not sure if this was relevant).
2. I used this specific order of commands in my document:

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfsetup{outdir=build/,suffix=,}
```

3. I build with `latexmk -auxdir=build/ -outdir=build/`

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `eps` file called `img.eps` in a directory `build`, you can include it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {build/} }
\begin{document}
Include graphics here: \includegraphics{img}
\end{document}
```

Compile with `pdflatex` and it automatically converts the file, leaving the `pdf` in the `build` directory, and compiles the whole thing together.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the build/ directory should be where the output files go, now where the input files are. But I think it started working...

Comment: `pdflatex --output-directory=build`

Comment: or `latexmk -outdir=build -pdf`